# Optimising a program to tally averages

Tags: math

Suppose I wanted to prove empirically that a 1d12 (twelve sided die) follows a rectangular distribution and 2d6 a normal distributions.

The quick and dirty way would be to tally about 1000 randomly generated numbers, put them in an array, and then calculate the mean and expected values from there.

But what if I wanted to save memory by using a running total instead of the 1000 member array?

Could I do something like this:

```
for (i =0; i < 1000; i++){
   x = Math.Random(1,6);
   runningTotal += x;
}

mean = runningTotal / 1000;
```

Comment: A single running total won't tell you if the 1d12 only gets you 1 & 12. You want a counter on each side, ie, an array with the size of 12, each member corresponds to how many that side comes up during the test.

Answer (score 0):

> Another approach [is] using deques is to maintain a sequence of recently
> added elements by appending to the right and popping to the left:

One idea would be something along the lines of this simple moving average recipe with Python's double ended `collections.deque`:

```
def moving_average(iterable, n=3):
    # moving_average([40, 30, 50, 46, 39, 44]) --> 40.0 42.0 45.0 43.0
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average
    it = iter(iterable)
    d = deque(itertools.islice(it, n-1))
    d.appendleft(0)
    s = sum(d)
    for elem in it:
        s += elem - d.popleft()
        d.append(elem)
        yield s / n
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#deque-recipes